# Reading json from csv gives a input error token not found

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
 id order_id    message created     
14  1609    {"dispatch_date":"2017-03-31"}  3/27/17 14:12       
31  1690    {"dispatch_date":"2017-03-31"}  3/27/17 14:44       
55  1723    {"dispatch_date":"2017-03-31"}  3/27/17 15:58       
105 1669    {"dispatch_date":"2017-04-01"}  3/27/17 16:32       
138 1749    {"dispatch_date":"2017-03-31"}  3/27/17 18:31       
244 1769    {"dispatch_date":"2017-04-01"}  3/28/17 10:12       
272 1748    {"dispatch_date":"2017-04-01"}  3/28/17 12:30
```

this is the q2 csv use for copy , help me with error stuck from two days

Comment: CREATE TABLE ot(
id integer,
order_id integer,
message json,
created timestamp
)
COPY ot (id, order_id, message, created) 
FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Q2.csv' 
WITH(FORMAT CSV,HEADER TRUE)
 this code i am using

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "-03" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 28-03...
COPY ot, line 2, column message: "28-03-2017"
SQL state: 22P02

this is the error

Comment: Your date format is `28-03-2017` or DD-MM-YYY while it should be YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: This is clearly not a CSV file.

Comment: `WITH(FORMAT CSV...` implies the delimiter is a `,` unless specified otherwise. I don't see `,` in your CSV example. Do they exist? If not you will need to explicitly set `DELIMITER <some_character>`.

Comment: Please post sql and complete error message in the question, **do not** put them in a comment.